# "The request is not supported" error (50) when using PeekNamedPipe from within a windows docker container

Tags: python, c#, docker, pywin32, named-pipes

When creating a windows named pipe from a service running on a host windows machine and communicating with it from client application running within a windows docker container, The following error occurred:

```
pywintypes.error: (50, 'PeekNamedPipe', 'The request is not supported.')
```

Note that other pipe operations performed from the client i.e: win32file.CreateFile, win32pipe.SetNamedPipeHandleState, win32file.ReadFile, win32file.WriteFile works properly.
So it seems that the issue is specific to PeekNamedPipe function.

The following code is the windows named pipe creation on the server side implemented in C#:

```
        private async Task RunServerAsync(string pipeName, CancellationToken token)
        {
            int clientId = 0;
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity();
                ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));  // all users
                ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Owner, PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
                //TODO add deny rule for network users

                var stream = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 4 * 1024, 4 * 1024, ps);

                await stream.WaitForConnectionAsync();
                Task nowait = RespondToRequestsAsync(stream, ++clientId);
            }
        }
```

The following code snippet shows the client side implemented in Python3.9 using win32 package:

Create connection:

```
            self._pipe_handle = win32file.CreateFile(
                self._pipe_name,
                win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,
                0,
                None,
                win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
                win32file.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                None
            )
            res = win32pipe.SetNamedPipeHandleState(
                self._pipe_handle, win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE, None, None)
```

peek command usage (Note that the WriteFile function works properly):

```
    def _send_request(self, request: str) -> bytes:
        """
        Send a JsonRpc request via the named pipe to the service.

        :param request: The JsonRpc request
        :return: The JsonRpc response
        :raises: ServiceResponseError
        """
        # Send request:
        request_buffer = request.encode('utf-8')
        request_message = self._add_delimiter(request_buffer)
        win32file.WriteFile(self._pipe_handle, request_message)

        # Get response:
        self._timed_out = False
        timeout_timer = Timer(self._timeout, self._handle_timeout)
        timeout_timer.start()

        while not self._timed_out:
            # Check that there's data to read from the pipe
            peek_buffer, bytesToRead, messageBytesToRead = win32pipe.PeekNamedPipe(
                self._pipe_handle, 0)
            if messageBytesToRead:  # There's a message to read in the pipe
                # Read the response
                result, buffer = win32file.ReadFile(
                    self._pipe_handle, messageBytesToRead)
                response = self._remove_delimiter(buffer)
                timeout_timer.cancel()
                return response
```

The docker images is a proprietary image using mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:3.5-20220809-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 as a base image
and run using the following command:

docker run -v C:\rep:C:\rep\ -v \.\pipe\pipename:\.\pipe\pipename -dit image_hash

**Also note that the code above works as expected when both client and server are running at the host machine. **

what could be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance